# No UAC appearing for newly installed applications

Tags: windows-10, web, uac

Recently I have noticed that my system doesn't show the UAC prompt whenever I install some application from another source, I have UAC on and everything is working fine, I also have an administrator account, Latest windows 10 version. But it never appears, is it a problem with Windows itself or has my device been compromised?

Comment: Do the new applications require admin access?

Comment: Some applications can run entirely in user space and don’t need elevated permissions. That would be my first guess, unless you explicitly know it requires elevated permissions and isn’t asking.

Comment: If you right click on an application and select "Run as administrator", does the UAC prompt appear?